# How to match input credentials with database credentials without typing them in laravel 8?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel-8

I have the credentials username, phonunmber, password and device serial number saved in my phpmyadmin database. I want to input the username, phonunmber and password and if all of them matches with device serial number in the databse, then the user can log in. How can i do that?

P.S device serial number is saved only in the database. I dont want to input as the other credentials. Just i want to check if the username, phonunumber, password and device serial number matches all together.

Comment: You'll want to look into [password hashing](https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-passwords-one-way-road-to-security/). Don't store passwords in your database! Hash them and store the result, then when you want to allow a user to login, hash their input and compare against the stored hash in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at "Manually authenticating users" section in https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Normally only email and password are used to authenticate user in Laravel

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```

But you can use any fields that you want to authenticate by passing them to `Auth::attempt`

```
$result = Auth::attempt([
    'username' => $request->username,
    'password' => $request->password,
    'phonunumber' => $request->phonunumber,
    'device_serial_number' => $request->device_serial_number
]);

if($result) {
    ...
}
```